# What is the reverse process of the repmat or repemel command?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of 50-by-1 that is demodulated data. As this matrix has only one element in each row, I want to repeat this only element 16 times in each row so the matrix become 50 by 16. I did it using the `repmat(A,16)` command in Matlab. Now at receiving end noise is also added in matrix of 50 by 16. I want to get it back of 50 by 1 matrix. How can I do this?

I tried averaging of all rows but it is not a valid method. How can I know when an error is occurring in this process?

Comment: "Not a valid method"... because? We can't diagnose when "an error" occurs in "this process" when you haven't adequately described "this process"

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a problem of the form `y = A * x + n`, where `y` is the observed data, `A` is a known linear transform, and `n` is noise. The least squares estimate is the simplest estimate of the unknown vector `x`. The keys here are to express the `repmat()` function as a matrix and the observed data as a vector (i.e., a 50*16x1 vector rather than a 50x16 matrix).

```
x = 10 * rand(50,1);                % 50x1 data vector;
A = repmat(eye(length(x)),[16,1]);  % This stacks 16 replicas of x.
n = rand(50*16,1);                  % Noise
y = A * x + n;                      % Observed data
xhat = A \ y;                       % Least squares estimate of x.
```

As for what the inverse (what I assume you mean by 'reverse') of `A` is, it doesn't have one. If you look at its rank, you'll see it is only 50. The best you can do is to use its pseudoinverse, which is what the `\` operator does.

I hope the above helps.